# Pthread loop function never gets called

Tags: c++, linux, android-ndk, pthreads

Below is my code, my problem is that readEvent() function never gets called.

```
Header file

class MyServer
{

    public :

        MyServer(MFCPacketWriter *writer_);

        ~MyServer();

        void startReading();

        void stopReading();

    private :

        MFCPacketWriter *writer;
        pthread_t serverThread;
        bool stopThread;



        static void *readEvent(void *);
};

CPP file

MyServer::MyServer(MFCPacketWriter *writer_):writer(writer_)
{
    serverThread = NULL;
    stopThread = false;
    LOGD(">>>>>>>>>>>>> constructed MyServer ");

}

MyServer::~MyServer()
{
    writer = NULL;
    stopThread = true;

}

void MyServer::startReading()
{
    LOGD(">>>>>>>>>>>>> start reading");
    if(pthread_create(&serverThread,NULL,&MyServer::readEvent, this) < 0)
    {
        LOGI(">>>>>>>>>>>>> Error while creating thread");
    }
}

void *MyServer::readEvent(void *voidptr)
{
    // this log never gets called
    LOGD(">>>>>>>>>>>>> readEvent");
    while(!MyServer->stopThread){

        //loop logic
    }

}

Another class

    MyServer MyServer(packet_writer);
    MyServer.startReading();
```

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using `std::thread`?

Comment: working on very old toolchain, for android that doesn't support std::Thread

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not calling [`pthread_join`](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Joining), your main thread is terminating without waiting for your worker thread to finish.

Here is a simplified example that reproduces the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

class Example {
public:
  Example () : thread_() {
    int rcode = pthread_create(&thread_, nullptr, Example::task, nullptr);
    if (rcode != 0) {
      std::cout << "pthread_create failed. Return code: " << rcode << std::endl;
    }
  }

  static void * task (void *) {
    std::cout << "Running task." << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
  }

private:
  pthread_t thread_;
};

int main () {
  Example example;
}
```

<kbd>[View Results](https://ideone.com/KzLPPg)</kbd>

No output is produced when running this program, even though `pthread_create` was successfully called with `Example::task` as the function parameter.

This can be fixed by calling `pthread_join` on the thread:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

class Example {
public:
  Example () : thread_() {
    int rcode = pthread_create(&thread_, nullptr, Example::task, nullptr);
    if (rcode != 0) {
      std::cout << "pthread_create failed. Return code: " << rcode << std::endl;
    }
  }

  /* New code below this point. */

  ~Example () {
    int rcode = pthread_join(thread_, nullptr);
    if (rcode != 0) {
      std::cout << "pthread_join failed. Return code: " << rcode << std::endl;
    }
  }

  /* New code above this point. */

  static void * task (void *) {
    std::cout << "Running task." << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
  }

private:
  pthread_t thread_;
};

int main () {
  Example example;
}
```

<kbd>[View Results](https://ideone.com/JN3t7f)</kbd>

Now the program produces the expected output:

> Running task.

In your case, you could add a call to `pthread_join` to the destructor of your `MyServer` class.